# Values of stat summary fun mean

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

I am trying to create a plot to compare running time of different algorithms. By running the below R code, I get the following plot, which I am generally statisfied with. However: It can be hard to read-off values from this graph, is there a way to get the plotted mean valeus for each DBMS for each instance? For example for `gplus-combined`, the value of `CacheDBMS` is around 50, while for `BranchDBMS` it is around 200.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(reorder(instance, V9), V9)) + 
  geom_point(aes(group=V2, colour=V2), stat='summary', fun.y='mean') +
  geom_line(aes(group=V2, colour=V2), stat='summary', fun.y='mean') +
  scale_y_log10() +
  ylab("Mean wall time") +
  xlab("") +
  ggtitle("Comparison of Database Management Systems") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="DBMS"))
```

[image: Output]

I want the y-values for each point. Preferably as a table, e.g.

```
BranchDBMS    gplus-combined    213.21
CacheDBMS     gplus-combined     48.68
```

**EDIT**

A small snippet (out of 10000-ish lines) of input data. I have removed unused columns, so the `V*` is not correct. But `V2` is the first column here, `V9` is the second and `instance` is the last.

```
BranchDBMS;      0.163352;  facebook-combined   
BranchDBMS;      0.169043;  facebook-combined   
BranchDBMS;      0.162545;  facebook-combined   
BranchDBMS;      0.159489;  facebook-combined   
BranchDBMS;      0.168414;  facebook-combined 
CacheDBMS ;      0.038515;  facebook-combined   
CacheDBMS ;      0.037179;  facebook-combined   
CacheDBMS ;      0.037385;  facebook-combined   
CacheDBMS ;      0.036514;  facebook-combined   
BranchDBMS;    281.149423;  gplus-combined    
BranchDBMS;    261.093502;  gplus-combined   
BranchDBMS;    258.816546;  gplus-combined     
CacheDBMS ;     22.442501;  gplus-combined    
CacheDBMS ;     22.377717;  gplus-combined   
CacheDBMS ;     22.469739;  gplus-combined   
CacheDBMS ;     22.451922;  gplus-combined
```

Comment: So you'd like to plot the values as labels of the points?

Comment: Either that, or simply print a table, e.g. BranchDBMS, gplus-combined, 213.21

Comment: Why don't you just compute the values before plotting (so you'd already have them in a table) and then you wouldn't need to use `stat="summary"` inside the ggplot. If you provide a small sample of your data, we could show you how

Comment: if you want to print the table, just summarise you data

Comment: @MLavoie how to summarise by grouping on both `V2` and `instance`?

Comment: with dplyr dt %>% group_by(V2, Instance) %>% summarise(meanx = mean(V9))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how to add the value labels directly to graph, using the built-in `iris` data frame:

```
p1 = ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", alpha=0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)), 
               size=3, show.legend=FALSE) +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1, lwd=1)))
```

`..y..` are the internally calculated means at each value of `Sepal.Width` for each `Species`. Because we used `alpha=0.5` for the line geom, `override.aes` allows us to have bolder lines in the legend.

[image]

One way to add a table of data values would be as follows:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)

# Change default fontsize for the data table
mytheme <- ttheme_default(
  core = list(fg_params=list(cex = 0.7)),
  colhead = list(fg_params=list(cex = 0.75)),
  rowhead = list(fg_params=list(cex = 0.75)))

# Create table (in this case I just show the first three values for each species)
tab = tableGrob(iris %>% group_by(Species, Sepal.Width) %>% 
             summarise(`Mean Sepal Length`=sprintf("%1.1f", mean(Sepal.Length))) %>%
               slice(1:3), theme=mytheme, rows=NULL)

# Lay out graph and table
grid.arrange(p1, tab, ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting negative values, even though the smallest number I have is around 0.03? Can this really be due to floating point errors?